# Test a service with ngrx

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, ngrx-store

I'm trying to test my PagesService where i have those two functions :

```
  setSelectedPage(selectedPage: Page): void {
    this.pagesStore.dispatch(PagesActions.setSelectedPage({ selectedPage }));
  }

  getSelectedPage(): Observable<Page> {
    return this.pagesStore.select(getSelectedPage);
  }
```

And this is my tests :

```
  it('should get selectedPage from store', () => { //Works fine
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
    });
    expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.selectedPage);
  });

  it('should set and get the new selectedPage from the store', () => { //Does not works
    service.setSelectedPage(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
    });
    expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
  });
```

The first test is working fine, but for the second test, Karma sends me an error, and tells me that content of testSelectedPage and initialState.pages.pages[1] are not equal.
What did i miss please ?

EDIT: Full Spec file

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockStore, provideMockStore } from '@ngrx/store/testing';
import { AppModule } from 'src/app/app.module';
import { SeoService } from 'src/app/pages/services/seo.service';
import { Page } from '../models/page.model';
import { pagesSeed, selectedPageSeed } from '../models/page.seed';
import { PagesActions } from '../store/action-types';
import { getSelectedPage } from '../store/pages.reducer';
import { PageDbService } from './page-db.service';

import { PagesService } from './pages.service';

fdescribe('PagesService', () => {
  let service: PagesService;
  const initialState = {
    pages: {
      selectedPage: selectedPageSeed,
      pages: pagesSeed,
    },
  };
  let store: MockStore;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        AppModule
      ],
      providers: [
        provideMockStore({ initialState }),
        PageDbService,
        SeoService
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(PagesService);
    store = TestBed.inject(MockStore);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
  
  it('should get selectedPage from store', (done) => {
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
      expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.selectedPage);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should set and get the new selectedPage from the store', (done) => {
    service.setSelectedPage(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
      expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
      done();
    });
  });
  
  // The 2 tests below Work fine but it not really test my service
  it('should get selectedPage from store', () => {
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    store.select(getSelectedPage).subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
    });
    expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.selectedPage);
  });
  
  it('should set and get the new selectedPage from the store', () => {
    const newSelectedPage = pagesSeed[1];
    store.dispatch(PagesActions.setSelectedPage({ selectedPage: newSelectedPage }));
    store.setState({ pages: { selectedPage: newSelectedPage } });
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    store.select(getSelectedPage).subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
    });
    expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(newSelectedPage);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `initialState.pages.selectedPage` null?

I think I have an idea of what could be going wrong. `subscribe` is async meaning it happens a bit in the future after your `expect`. I would take advantage of the `done` function from `jasmine`.

```
                                           // add done callback
  it('should get selectedPage from store', (done) => { //Works fine
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
      // do your assertion here
      expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.selectedPage);
      // call done to let Jasmine know you're done with the unit test
      done();
    });
    
  });

  it('should set and get the new selectedPage from the store', (done) => { //Does not works
    service.setSelectedPage(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
    let testSelectedPage: Page = null;
    service.getSelectedPage().subscribe(selectedPage => {
      testSelectedPage = selectedPage;
      expect(testSelectedPage).toEqual(initialState.pages.pages[1]);
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: initialState.pages.selectedPage is not null but filled with fake data. I already tried Done and fakeAsync tricks but didn't worked :(

Comment: When you call `service.setSelectedPage` does it actually disturb the store? I think you're not mocking the store properly where it doesn't change the store when that action is dispatched.

Comment: I added my full spec file in original post. Do i mock the store properly ?

Comment: Sorry I missed that, I am not sure then.